# Find and replace for a bullet list to html style

Tags: vba, macos, replace, vbscript, ms-word

I want to find instances of bullet lists, to replace with html tagged lists. Please see below for an example:

**my_doc.docx**
...

```
text,text,text
My bullet list:
   • List point one
   • List point two
Some more text here.
```

...

A find and replace resulting in

...

```
text,text,text
My bullet list:
<ul>
<li>List point one</li>
<li>List point two</li>
</ul>
Some more text here.
```

...

I've tried `find and replace` for the bullet characters; doesn't work as it's formatting. Also tried `find and replace` for lines with style "List bullet" and any other list styles I can find; doesn't work, (maybe because I'm using Word for Mac which seems buggy)

EDIT:
I have the following VBScript that finds lines in my document that have bullet styling. I now need this script to rewrite the line it finds with < li> tags on the end.

```
Sub FindBullet()
Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
Dim count As Integer

count = 0
Selection.WholeStory
With Selection
    For Each oPara In .Paragraphs
    If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType = _
    WdListType.wdListBullet Then

          count = count + 1

            # from here down it gets shaky!!!

            With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
              .Text = #How do i convert the oPara to a string here?!?
              .Forward = True
              .Wrap = wdFindContinue
              .Format = False
              .MatchCase = True
              .MatchWholeWord = False
              .MatchWildcards = False
              .MatchSoundsLike = False
              .MatchAllWordForms = False

              .ClearFormatting
              With .replacement
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = # how do i specify this is where i want the "<li>" & oPara & "</li>"
              End With
              .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        End If
    Next
End With
'Gives you the count of bullets in a document
MsgBox count & " replacements"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use (**InsertBefore** and **InsertAfter**) to insert text in the paragraph.
This works on Word Mac.

```
Sub FindBullet()
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
Set myStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("Body text") ' replacement style
bulletList = WdListType.wdListBullet

 ' each list instead of each paragraph of the document
For Each thisList In ActiveDocument.Lists
      For Each p In thisList.ListParagraphs
           If p.Range.ListFormat.ListType = bulletList Then
                p.Style = myStyle ' change the style to "Body text" 
                p.Range.InsertBefore ("<li>")
                Set aRange = p.Range
                aRange.End = aRange.End - 1
                aRange.InsertAfter ("</li>")
                count = count + 1
            End If
      Next
Next
MsgBox count & " replacements"
End Sub
```